# Regex pass validation

Tags: .net, regex, validation, passwords

I would like to know how one could validate a password with regex.

I tried using lookahaed assertions but I somehow failed. I don't know how I can match a certain length of a string.

My conditions are :

- At least 8 characters
- At least one digit
- At least one lower English letter
- At least one upper English letter
- At least one symbol of !@#$%-
- Only above characters are allowed

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are in the right step with lookahead assertions.

Your requirements can be broken down to this :

- (?=.{8,})
- (?=.*\d)
- (?=.*[a-z])
- (?=.*[A-Z])
- (?=.*[!@#$%-])
- [\da-zA-Z!@#$%-]*

Putting it all together you end up with this :

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%-])[\da-zA-Z!@#$%-]*$");
```

Which can in turn be explained by this :

```
"
^                   # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?=                 # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   .                   # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      {8,}                # Between 8 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(?=                 # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   .                   # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \d                  # Match a single digit 0..9
)
(?=                 # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   .                   # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [a-z]               # Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
)
(?=                 # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   .                   # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [A-Z]               # Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z”
)
(?=                 # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   .                   # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [!@#$%-]            # Match a single character present in the list below
                          # One of the characters “!@#$”
                          # The character “%”
                          # The character “-”
)
[\da-zA-Z!@#$%-]    # Match a single character present in the list below
                       # A single digit 0..9
                       # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
                       # A character in the range between “A” and “Z”
                       # One of the characters “!@#$”
                       # The character “%”
                       # The character “-”
   *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$                   # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%-]).{8,}$
```

Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [!@#$%-]                 any character of: '!', '@', '#', '$',
                             '%', '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{8,}                    any character except \n (at least 8 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

---

Really, you shouldn't enforce this kind of password though.  See this noteworthy xkcd comic for a fair explanation why

> Through 20 years of effort, we've successfully trained everyone to use passwords that are hard for humans to remember, but easy for computers to guess.

[image: XKCD password strength]

Comment: While this is correct, I think you forgot the final requirement.

Comment: Thank you!Nice comic by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:
(Oops, better make this at least correct)
*expanded*

```
^
(?=[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%-]{8,}$)
(?=.*[0-9])
(?=.*[a-z])
(?=.*[A-Z])
(?=.*[!@#$%-])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you need to use a single regex for all of these rules? It's more common, and more readable, to test each one separately. For example:

```
if(pass.length < 8 || ! pass.matches(/[0-9]/) || ! pass.matches(/[a-z]/)
   || ! pass.matches(/[A-Z]/) || ! pass.matches(/[!@#$%-]/)
   || pass.matches(/[^0-9A-Za-z!@#$%-]/))
{
    . . . // reject password
}
```

Comment: My requirement specifications are regex... Thank you anyway!